# Square root of a sequence given by a linear recurrence relation

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, recurrences

This question is closely related to [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316374/linear-recurrence-relation-for-square-of-sequence-given-recursively) but in a sense a converse of it. Let us concentrate for simplicity on a third order relation $x_{n+3}=ax_{n+2}+bx_{n+1}+cx_n$ with given intial terms $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and assume $x_n\geq0$ for all $n$. Assume we fix $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ generically and vary $x_1,x_2,x_3\in\mathbb{R}$. We are looking for a second order recurrence $y_{n+2}=ry_{n+1}+sy_n$ such that $y_n^2 = x_n$ for all $n$. For generic $a,b,c$ there is only a finite number of options for the unknown coefficients $(r,s)$. Hence, only for $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ lying in a certain two-dimensional set can we find a second-order relation satisfied by $\pm\sqrt{x_n}$ (this is because $\pm\sqrt{x_{3}}=\pm r\sqrt{x_{2}}+\pm s\sqrt{x_{1}}$ has to hold). We restrict our attention to $(a,b,c)=(\alpha^2+\beta^2+\alpha\beta,-\alpha^2\beta^2-\alpha^3\beta-\alpha\beta^3,\alpha^3\beta^3)$ for some $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{C}$, since in that case we can find a solution $(r,s)=(\alpha+\beta,-\alpha\beta)$.

Now my question is simply: what can we say for general $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$? For a vast majority of $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ no linear relation of the form $y_{n+2}=ry_{n+1}+sy_n$ will be satisfied for the square roots of $(x_n)$. But can it be that the square roots still have to satisfy a second order recursion of a more general form? Trivially, the roots satisfy a third order non-linear recursion (the initial one), so the question is basically to find out whether the ''order-collapse'' (passing from order 3 to order 2) happens indeed only for special $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and not generally. If this is the case, it should also be possible to prove it. Is there a good intuition as to why it should (or should not) hold?

Example 1: Here is a concrete example (see also Problem 6 [here](https://www.egmo.org/egmos/egmo9/)). Take $(a,b,c,x_1,x_2,x_3)=(m,m,-1,1,1,4)$. For $m=2,10$ the roots follow a linear second order recurrence with $(r,s)=(\sqrt{m-1},1)$. For other values of $m$ we would have to perturb the initial terms $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(1,1,4)$ to ensure that the same recurrence still works. But what if we insist on keeping the initial terms as they are and take, say, $m=3$? Is the whole magic lost, or can we still find a relation for the roots that is closely related to $y_{n+2}=ry_{n+1}+sy_n$? Intuitively, I would hope that (e.g., for $m=3$) there is a more general (but still algebraically elegant) second order recursion that holds for any $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, with coefficients depending on $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, and that simply degenerates to $y_{n+2}=ry_{n+1}+sy_n$ for $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(1,1,4)$.

Example 2 (from a comment below): Take $(a,b,c,x_1,x_2,x_3)=(0,0,1,1,4,9)$. We get $(\alpha,\beta)=(\exp(2\pi i/3),\exp(4\pi i/3))$, hence $(r,s)=(-1,-1)$, so the equation $y_{n+2}=-y_{n+1}-y_n$ will drive the square roots, however only for specific choices of the initial terms. E.g., $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(1,4,9)$ obviously works, but the question is how to generalize the relation to an arbitrary choice of the initial parameters.

Bonus question: Above we have worked with reals. Now we assume additonally $x_1,x_2,x_3,a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$. If $\sqrt{x_n}\in\mathbb{Z}$ for all $n$, does it follow that the order-collapse has to occur (i.e., the square roots satisfy a second order (linear?) recurrence)?

Comment: Let's look at a simple example, $x_{n+3}=x_n$, $x_1=1$, $x_2=4$, $x_3=9$. Does the sequence $1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,\dots$ satisfy a second-order (linear constant-coefficient) recurrence?

Comment: Let try it the other way around. Let start with a generic (say MiPo has distinct roots) second order recurrence $y_n=\lambda_1r_1^n +\lambda_2r_2^n$. If we square this, we get $\lambda_1^2(r_1^2)^n+2\lambda_1\lambda_2(r_1r_2)^n+\lambda_2^2(r_2^2)^n$, and thus the third order recurrence relation must have a minimal Polynomial with roots $r_1^2,r_2^2,r_1r_2$ and the coefficients must looks as above. One should be able to deal with the case where the minimal polynomial hasthe same root twice analogously.

Comment: One can check if a sequence satisfies a linear recurrence, by requiring that a certain determinant vanish. In this case, you will have a 3x3-matrix, where the entries are $\sqrt{x_i}$, $\sqrt{x_{i+1}},\dotsc$ (a Toeplitz matrix).